# How to append data refer by ID in Google Script Apps?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I try using Google Script Apps for append data to Google Spreadsheet null Column **"rate"** like:

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | name  | rate |  
+----+-------+------+
| 1  | Item1 |      |
+----+-------+------+
| 2  | Item2 |      |
+----+-------+------+
| 3  | Item3 |      |
+----+-------+------+
```

How modification bellow code to work fine like **id=1&rate=good** for append Column value **rate** with refer by call id 1,2,3 or any more and work to append value like

```
+----+-------+------+
| id | name  | rate |  
+----+-------+------+
| 1  | Item1 | good |
+----+-------+------+
| 2  | Item2 |      |
+----+-------+------+
| 3  | Item3 |      |
+----+-------+------+
```

```
function doGet(e) {
  var id = e.parameter.id || 1;
  var rate = e.parameter.rate || "";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10S8Igzt1tpqUBgJHVKpny-2s6G3Y3-vFsLMvlZVqpkc/edit#gid=810612111");
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("list_film");
  return insertData(sheet, id,rate);
}

function insertData(sheet, id,rate){
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().filter(([a]) => a == id);
  var data = rows.appendRow([rate]);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(data).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
``
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- When it accesses to `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec?id=1&rate=good`, you want to put the value of `good` to the same row of the ID of the column "C".

In this case, I would like to propose to modify the function of `insertData` as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function insertData(sheet, id, rate){
  var ranges = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().reduce((ar, [a], i) => {
    if (a == id) ar.push("C" + (i + 1));
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sheet.getRangeList(ranges).setValue(rate);
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("Done.").setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

- In this modification, the range list is created and the value is put using the range list. By this, when the same IDs are existing, the value of `rate` is put to each row of the column "C".
- If you want to put the values to other column, please modify above script.

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Class RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list)